# Gnomish themes won't install

Tags: 14.04, themes

I am new to Ubuntu, as well as using the terminal to do pretty much anything.I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04. I added the repository for the gnome themes, and updated.But when I go to install any of the themes, the terminal says cannot locate the packages.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gnomishdark-theme` is not not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme that you are looking for is, "gnomishdark".

To install this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnomishdark
```

Comment: @Jacob Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧).